# Do ICs sink their input current?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit

I know this question may be **very** stupid, but it comes from a true beginner, and a Google search came up inconclusive.

When porting high or low the input pins on an integrated circuit (particularly CMOS), are the input current sinked or sourced ? To me it makes sense that they would be sinked, but I am not finding the information on it, as googling with the terms 'sinking' or 'sourcing' just brings up pages about those terms.

Comment: Input pins can be of different types. they can be pulled up for instance. In this case they will source if the input signal is low. They can be pulled down, then they sink when the input is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the technology.

Standard TTL sources current when pulled low. CMOS can have pull-ups or pull downs that will source or sink current respectively.

Also, be aware that with CMOS devices there is also input capacitance. That means while switching they sink on high edges and source on falling edges. As such when driving an input with say a high frequency clock, there is significant currents involved in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

Input pins are usually high impedance.

In other words they act as if floating. However some ICs have internal pullup or pulldown resistors on some pins to bias the pin high or low.

Answer (score 0):

I2L logic has PNP inputs. RTL has NPN inputs. And opamps for really low noise might user either NPN or PNP.